# High mass bodies that are stacked on top of each other are wobbling while sitting idly in Box2D

Tags: c++, physics, game-design, box2d, debugging

I'm recreating the SaturnV rocket to-scale in Box2D, which so-far involves 3 very massive rectangular bodies stacked on top of each other (1-2 million kg each). Box2D advises not to use such high mass objects, but so far my only issue with doing that occurs when the rocket is sitting on the ground, during which the top two stages start to wobble with increasing "amplitude", ultimately falling over. I'm wondering how to prevent or circumvent this, as I want to be as close to reality as possible when modeling the rocket.

I've tried putting more weld-joints on the corners instead of just the lower-middle. Distance and friction joints also have't done much, nor has changing the stiffness/dampening properties of the weld joints.

Comment: I'm afraid that, apart from what you say regarding the use of too heavy objects, this is a limitation of the engine as explained here: https://box2d.org/documentation/md__d_1__git_hub_box2d_docs_loose_ends.html#autotoc_md126

Comment: Have you considered scaling your masses? It's not unusual in games to change the default units, for instance when making a miniature-sized game we don't make our objects 0.01 units tall, we just declare that 1 unit is 1 cm and adjust the gravity acceleration vector to compensate for this altered length scale while maintaining correct physics. You can do the same with mass (without changing gravity, since the mass term cancels out in acceleration due to gravity anyway).

Comment: I was dreading to go down that pathway cause I thought that surely something physics-related would change but it doesn't seem like the case. Thanks for the replies